# Proving that an open rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is contained in an n-ball $B_{r}(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

The question says: Let $|x_{k} - a_{k}| < \delta, 1 \leq k \leq n,$ be a rectanglein $\mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that it is contained in an n-ball $B_{r}(a),$ and find a minimal r for which this is true.

The answer at the back of the book says that $r_{minimal} = \delta \sqrt{n}/2.$ but I do not know how to prove that it is contained in an n-ball $B_{r}(a),$ and why this is the minimal radius, could anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution has a typo; the minimal radius should be $\delta \sqrt{n}$.

---

The squared distance of an element $x$ of the rectangle from the center $a$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - a_k)^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^n \delta^2 = \delta^2 n.$$
That is, every point of the rectangle is within distance $\delta \sqrt{n}$ of $a$,
i.e. the rectangle is contained in the ball of radius $\delta \sqrt{n}$ centered at $a$.

To see that this radius cannot be any smaller, note that for any $\epsilon > 0$ the point $x$ with components $x_k = a_k + (1-\epsilon)\delta$ is distance exactly $\delta \sqrt{n(1-\epsilon)}$ from $a$.

Comment: I do not understand your part of showing that this radius can not be smaller.... could you explain more details please?

Comment: @hopefully The point of the rectangle that is farthest from the center is the "corner," which has distance exactly $\delta \sqrt{n}$, so you cannot make the radius of the ball any smaller, lest you exclude this "corner" of the rectangle. But this isn't quite right because the definition of your rectangle does not contain the boundary. But this can be fixed by looking at points arbitrarily close to a "corner" instead of the corner itself.